# PHP using Doctrine Criteria obj, no groupBy function

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

It seems that there is no `groupBy` method inside [the Doctrine 2 `Criteria` class](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections). How to add one to my `Criteria` object?

[image]

Comment: What code have you written? Are you using the Query Builder? if so, the method 'groupBy('field_name')' exists.

Comment: Do you want to `groupBy` or `orderBy`?

Comment: I want to `GroupBy`. I will probably try to use Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder ... (Thanks Wilt for the edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use the `expr()` method and access [the `GroupBy` expression class](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Expr/GroupBy.php) from there. I think `groupBy` should be accessible through this method like normally:

```
/** @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria $criteria */
$criteria->expr()->groupBy( ... your condition ... );
```

Just like you would do in a `QueryBuilder` instance:

```
/** @var \Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder $queryBuilder */
$queryBuilder->expr()->groupBy( ... your condition ... );
```

Comment: it can't seem to find groupBy(), says the function does not exist?

Comment: Here is the exact error I get ("message": "Attempted to call an undefined method named \"groupBy\" of class \"Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\ExpressionBuilder\".",)

Comment: @JosephAstrahan I am not sure what happened here. I am also unable to find it. Here [all the avaiable methods in that `ExpressionBuilder`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/collections/1.3/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ExpressionBuilder.html). Not sure if the API changed or I made a mistake previously. Since the answer was accepted and upvoted I would almost expect that it is the first.

Answer (score 0):

The `groupBy` method is available with the QueryBuilder Class:

Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder

Comment: Which does not help out much when dealing with criteria objects.

Comment: Raised feature request on GitHub, https://github.com/doctrine/collections/issues/347 , hope we can get this functionality